# Can't define 'FARGATE' AWS Batch compute environment from CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-batch

I am trying to define an AWS Batch Compute Environment with type 'FARGATE' from the Python AWS CDK, but it doesn't seem to be available. This is what I have so far:

```
compute_resources = ComputeResources(
    vpc=vpc,
    minv_cpus=0,
    maxv_cpus=30,
    type=ComputeResourceType.SPOT,
    desiredv_cpus=0,
    vpc_subnets=SubnetSelection(subnets=vpc.private_subnets),
    security_groups=security_groups
)

compute_env = ComputeEnvironment(
    self,
    'ComputeEnvironment',
    managed=True,
    enabled=True,
    compute_resources=compute_resources,
    service_role=batch_service_role
)
```

I am trying to set `type=ComputeResourceType.FARGATE_SPOT`, but it doesn't seem available. Is the only way to do this via `CfnComputeEnvironment`?

EDIT:

As per the AWS Batch docs, I would expect `FARGATE_SPOT` to be available as a `ComputeResourceType`, but it's not.

[AWS Batch docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-batch-computeenvironment-computeresources.html#cfn-batch-computeenvironment-computeresources-type):

[image]

[AWS CDK API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_batch/ComputeResourceType.html):

[image: Image of ComputeResourceType AWS CDK Docs]

Comment: "it doesn't seem available" - what does it mean? Do you get any specific error message?

Comment: It's not available in the AWS CDK API. I've edited the question with further info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComputeEnvironment` is Level 2 construct (high level) and as you pointed out it does not support Fargate. But if you go to **Level 1** construct [CfnComputeEnvironment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_batch/CfnComputeEnvironment.html) you can do this.

The reason is that it directly maps to CloudFormation's [AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-batch-computeenvironment.html) which you linked in your question.